# Cron job and top level domain

Tags: php, dns, cron

The site I'm working on, is using the top level domain (`.nl`/`.be`) to define its language and with it the database it should use. This allows the same website to be used for multiple domains, having each their own content, but the same layout.

All works well, except when it gets to Cron jobs. The domain is used to define which database to be used via the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. With a cronjob, the file is called directly without the use of the domain (local domain hierarchy), hence it cannot derive which database/language it should use.

Is there a good way to have cron jobs use the same principle or am I stuck with having to send along a variable to define which database/language it should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push a value inside the environment variables:

```
@daily     HTTP_HOST=www.example.nl php /path/to/script.php
```

The environment variable should appear inside `$_SERVER` to make it work as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do that is put the cron in web root, use wget http://example.com/cron.php or GET and http_host will be set automatically - make sure you build logic to prevent abuse either through htaccess or limiting execution to certain ips